# When to use R, when to use SQL?

Tags: sql, r, database, data.table

I have a moderate sized database with many joins and lookup tables.

I am more familiar with R than with SQL, and I am using MySQL.

### My Question:

At what point is it beneficial to stop increasing the complexity of an SQL statement in favor of the data subsetting functionality in R (e.g., `merge`, `*apply`, `maply`, `dlply`, etc.)in R.

On one hand, SQL's join is easier than selecting all contents of each table and using the R `merge` function to join them. Also, doing the conditional selects in SQL would reduce the amount of data that has to be imported to R; but the speed difference is not significant.

On the other hand, a big join with a complex where clause becomes less easy to understand than the R syntax.

Below I have some *untested* code for illustrative purposes: I am asking this question at before having working code, and the answer to my question doesn't require working code (although this is always appreciated) - the "most elegant approach", "fewest lines", or "amazing implementation of X" are always appreciated, but what I am particularly interested in is the "most sensible / practical / canonical / based on first principles" rationale.

I am interested in the general answer of which steps should use a SQL `where` clause and which steps would be easier to accomplish using R.

### Illustration:

#### Database description

there are three tables: `a`, `ab`, and `b`. Tables `a` and `b` each have a primary key `id`. They have a many-many relationship that is represented by a lookup table, `ab`, which contains fields `ab.a_id` and `ab.b_id` that join to `a.id` and `b.id`, respectively. Both tables have a `time` field, and a has a `group` field.

#### Goal:

Here is a minimal example of the join and subsetting that I want to do;

(MySQL naming of elements, e.g. `a.id` is equivalent to `a$id` in R)

1. Join tables `a` and `b` using `ab`, appending multiple values of `b.time` associated with each `a.id` as a new column;

   ```
   select a_time, b.time, a.id, b.id from 
          a join ab on a.id = ab.a_id 
          join b on b.id = ab.b_id and then append b.time for distinct values of b.id;
   ```
2. I don't need repeated values of b.time, I only need a value of `b.max`: for repeated values of `b.time` joined to each `a.id`, `b.max` is the value of `b.time` closest to but not greater than `a.time`

   ```
   b.max <- max(b.time[b.time < a.time))
   ```
3. append the value `dt <- a.time - b.max` to the table, for example, in R,
4. for each distinct value in `a.group`,   select which(min(x.dt)))

   ```
   x.dt <- a.time - b.max
   ```

Comment: The "closest to but not greater than" sounds like a `roll=TRUE` join in package [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/). That operation can be tortuously slow in SQL but very fast with short syntax in R. There is also `locf` in `zoo` and `xts` and other packages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually do the data manipulations in SQL 
until the data I want is in a single table, 
and then, I do the rest in R.
Only when there is a performance issue
do I start to move some of the computations to the database.
This is already what you are doing.

Computations involving timestamps often 
become unreadable in SQL
(the "[analytic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Window_function)", similar to `ddply`, 
are supposed to simplify this,
but I think they are not available in MySQL).

However, your example can probably be written entirely in SQL as follows (not tested).

```
-- Join the tables and compute the maximum
CREATE VIEW t1 AS
SELECT a.id    AS a_id, 
       a.group AS a_group,
       b.id    AS b_id,
       a.time  AS a_time, 
       a.time - MAX(b.time) AS dt
FROM   a, b, ab
WHERE  a.id = ab.a_id AND b.id = ab.b_id
AND    b.time < a.time
GROUP  BY a.id, a.group, b.id;

-- Extract the desired rows
CREATE VIEW t2 AS 
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1, (SELECT group, MIN(dt) AS min_dt FROM t1) X
WHERE t1.a_id = X.a_id 
AND   t1.b_id = X.b_id 
AND   t1.a_group = X.a.group;
```

Comment: Precicely, subset in SQL and only bring into R what you need for your analysis.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but using views in MySQL is slower than using data.table in R (even though the MySQL server is much faster than my my desktop) - I asked a related question on dba.SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/when-to-use-views-in-mysql and it appears views are known to be slow. Still, the speed penalty is on the order of a minute, which is tolerable if annowying.

Answer (score 13):

Why not [both](http://www.r-bloggers.com/make-r-speak-sql-with-sqldf/) SQL and R — within R using the [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package? These  [examples](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Examples) show how you can either use the `sqldf` function with either R data frames or through a connection to an existing database. That way, you have the flexibility to do either as the idiom sees fit.

Comment: I actually do use both. I have a function `query` that wraps around the `dbSendQuery()` function, so I can, e.g., `query("select * from a ...)`. But the question is, how complex should the SQL queries be, and when should I just import the table into R and do the joins, selections, and basic arithmetic (min, max, +, -, *, /, etc), in R. My question would be "which idioms are best suited to R vs MySQL.

Comment: It seems like people keep voting this up and down. I think I'll leave my answer in case it is useful to others who didn't quite get that this was already being used, and maybe it will help them out. That, and I like roller coaster rides. Whee!

Comment: +1; although not featured in the examples, sqldf can connect directly to the database; quite useful. thanks.